# Grouping rows via two different columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask if grouping rows with the same value but came from different columns is possible.

I have a scenario that we should sum up the total minutes if the records are found "continuous" transactions by checking if the **STARTDATETIME** column matches the previous data of **ENDDATETIME** column if they are the same. See image link below for reference.

Thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: not is posible in a single query. but You should run two queries. for each row in the first query run another query where the q2.end=q1.start; and for each row in q2 do your task

Comment: Or just run one query

Comment: This answer from @Gordon Linoff might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410058/2610061

Comment: Thanks guys for answering. Specially to you @cars10m. Helps a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified Gordon Linoff's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410058/2610061) ( see my comment under the question):

```
SELECT 
  c.employee_id
  ,MIN(c.start_date) AS start_date
  ,MAX(c.end_date) AS end_date
  ,COUNT(*) AS numcontracts,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,MIN(c.start_date),MAX(c.end_date)) AS timediff
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
    c0.*
    ,(@rn := @rn + COALESCE(startflag, 0)) AS cumestarts
    FROM 
    (SELECT c1.*,
             (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM contracts c2
                  WHERE c1.employee_id = c2.employee_id AND
                    c1.start_date = c2.end_date
                 )
             ) AS startflag
          FROM contracts c1
          ORDER BY employee_id, start_date

    ) c0 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) params

  ) c
GROUP BY c.employee_id, c.cumestarts
```

http://rextester.com/VOGMU19779

`timediff` contains the minutes passed in the combined interval.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it a while a go with few data. But when I've removed other parameters, it causes the query to load 16s. I'm still working on its indexes though. Thanks!